# Creating quarterly timeseries Matlab

Tags: matlab, input, time-series

I am trying to create a timeseries in Matlab, from my GDP, and referencing it to the quarterly timearray that I have, but can't do it properly.

```
Q' = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4.....]
```

and

```
Year' = [2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002.....]
```

and their respective value. 
I would like that the first value from my GDP references to a days based time where for example        2013 Q2 is: 2013-04-01. (If you have suggestions about a weeks based times, please share it)

```
GDP.TimeInfo.Units = 'days';
GDP.TimeInfo.StartDate = '02-Jan-2001';
GDP.TimeInfo.Format = 'dd-mmm-yyyy';
GDP.Time = date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a date vector containing the first day of each quarter using the `datestr` function and setting the time to 00:00:00 as you don't need it.

```
N = size(Year,1);
dateVector = datestr([Year,3*(Q-1)+1,ones(N,1),zeros(N,1),zeros(N,1),zeros(N,1)):
```

This gives you

```
DateVec =

01-Jan-2000
01-Apr-2000
01-Jul-2000
01-Oct-2000
...
```

You can initialize your timeseries with your GDP data vector and the date vector:

```
GDP = timeseries(DataVector,DateVector);
```